# Three coloring problem for a planar map where each region has an even number of neighbouring regions

Tags: linear-algebra, graph-theory, algorithms, coloring

I recently tried to read the book "Introduction to Algorithms: A Creative Approach" by Udi Manber. I want to go through the Exercises one by one. Here is the one I have difficulties in solving:

> Prove that a planar map can be colored with three colors, such that
> every two neighboring regions are colored with different colors, if
> and only if each region has an even number of neighboring regions. Two
> regions are considered neighbors if they have an edge in common.

I believe we have odd number of regions, with each region being surrounded by an even number of neighbouring regions that can be colored by two colors, and the last color is reserved for the region which is surrounded.

However, when applying induction, I'm struggling to find a method to either decrease or increase the size of the problem while maintaining the necessary properties.

For example, adding one region results in an odd number of neighbours for the neighbours of the added region. Consequently, adding another region introduces multiple cases that complicates my solution.

Comment: I don't understand, neither direction is correct: a triangle is two colorable on the faces (so 3 colorable), and this 4-regular graph is not 4 colorable on vertices https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/242807/planar-graph-with-a-chromatic-number-of-4-where-all-vertices-have-a-degree-of-4

Comment: A triangle has only one neighbouring region. So it does not have the desired property. However, if it is two colorable, then it could be three colorable, as well.

Comment: In terms of graph theory, it's dual will still be a vertex of degree 3, but you can easily find 3-colorable graphs with odd faces and no loops or multi edges in the dual.